# what are the equivalent folders for values-small, values-normal, values-large, values-xlarge for API>=13?

Tags: java, android

I want to replace the deprecated (from API 13 upwards) folders:

- values-small
- values-normal
- values-large
- values-xlarge

by values-sw(N)dp and/or values-sh(N)dp folders.

since the docs say:

> small screens are at least 426dp x 320dp
>
> normal screens are at least 470dp x 320dp
>
> large screens are at least 640dp x 480dp
>
> xlarge screens are at least 960dp x 720dp

Can you confirm that this is correct (if **only width** is considered):

- values-small = values-sw426dp
- values-normal = values-sw470dp
- values-large = values-sw640dp
- values-xlarge= values-sw960dp

Since the deprecated folder-structure also considers hight and the docs say that even combining is possible:

> If the available height is a concern for you, then you can do the same
>   using the h(N)dp qualifier. Or, even combine the w(N)dp and h(N)dp
>   qualifiers if you need to be really specific.

what would be the combined equivalent folders for the mentioned ones? I cannot find an example of a combined folder....

thank you!

Comment: I would just stop thinking in terms of the original four buckets. Just decide at what width(s) (or whatever) in `dp` you want to switch your UI, and create resource sets for those.

Answer (score 0):

The [Adaptive UI material design guidelines](http://www.google.com/design/spec/layout/adaptive-ui.html) measure things out in terms of device width alone, noting a number of breakpoints:

- 600dp as the smallest width to consider a two-pane layout (i.e., summary and detail, master/detail, etc) rather than two separate screens
- 1600dp as the 'maximum width' of content in most cases

You'll note they also use a 'column' system to denote separate breakpoints for switching to showing more content - those breakpoints include 480dp and 840dp.

Consider using these breakpoints for designing your app, rather than using the previous buckets.